# Setting View Access Control on SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am advocating users in my organisation to use SharePoint for sales management and data tracking (instead of Excel), have build up a list using SharePoint and encounter following business compliance requirements, would appreciate for your input and suggestion on how to handle this:

My organisation sales team is structured as such:

- Team 1 (London)
- Team 2 (Birmingham)
- Team 3 (Liverpool)
- Team 4 (Edinburgh)

Currently I have created a client tracker in such format in the SharePoint list:

**Client Name | Team | Sales Rep Name | Revenue | Aging | Remarks**

Where our business compliance have such requirements:

- Ideally this list will be maintained by sales rep themselves (if not it will be limited to 1 rep + 1 team lead within the sales team) where they can create a new item and input the client name and details
- Sales rep should not be able to view client name by other teams, but it is ok for the sales rep to view items created by other sales rep within the same team
- However for the Head of Sales should be able to view items created by all sales teams

Questions:

1. Is above business requirement possible to be done by SharePoint? Due to enterprise environment we can only look at JSON or PowerApps, no external apps or add ons shall be installed.  What are the possible solutions if not workarounds available? I have thought of creating different views for each sales team however believe it is still possible for them to view other team's entries by switching the views in SharePoint list, hence it is not really an effective control of information after all.
2. For the aging computation, possible to set it to business days only?

Would try not to create different lists and linking back-and-forth using lookup or flow as the list needs to be sustainable in the long term as it will go up to 1000 items on annual basis
Appreciate for all the advice and comments so that I can educate the business users better, thanks!